# Scale to select time period - linear or exponential?

Tags: mobile, mobile-application, ux-designer

in my app, I  need to allow customers to select a period of time between 15 minutes to up to 24 hours.

Now, I'm a bit confused of which is the best way to create a scale, linear or exponential.

The linear scale is simple, it will be a scale from 0 to 24 with 0.15 as step value.

The exponential one will be a bit different (not 100% sure yet, if you have any suggestion on this as well, feel free to write them down as well even if it's not the real question)

I  was thinking about having the scale behave like the following:

```
0
0.15
0.30
0.45
1
1.30
2
2.30
3
3.30
4
4.30
5
6
7
8
9
10
12
14
16
18
20
22
24
```

But to be honest, I  don't know how user usually reacts to exponential scale and I also don't know if they are good for selecting time periods.

**So the question is: Linear or Exponential? which scale is better for this?**

Thanks for any suggestion and feedback

Comment: We need to know more about the use-case for the time period selection: do the periods need to be precise? are they for a fixed length? Is there a possibility that someone might require a period of 8.15? - These are really questions you should be asking your users: they will tell you what they need.

Comment: Hopefully these numbers are just used for posting this question, because I saw 1.30 and read it as 1.3 hours rather than 1.5 hours.

Comment: yes, they are just explanatory

Answer (score 2):

A pure guess based on the limited info in your question: it looks like you're trying to use a dropdown or some other list based selector for this.

A more simple side-step to the linear/exponential question may be to offer two dropdowns: one for hours and another for quarter hours.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQhKxX.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: I'm currently using a slider, but using two is an idea that needs to be discussed with the team.